# jQuery results filtering multi filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, filter

I am working on an filter option for a results page.
I have something thats working fine with one filter but when other filters are clicked its goes wrong. The problem is that when you filter a color and a size it will show the color rows and the size rows even if colored filter doenst have that size.

This is the filter javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
        var showAll = true;
        $('.resuts_show_hide').hide();
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            showAll = false;    
            $("[data-row-" + $(this).data('type') + "=" + $(this).val() + "]").parent().show();
        });
        if(showAll){
            $('.resuts_show_hide').show();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

So i thought lets do this:

```
$("[data-row-" + $(this).data('type') + "=" + $(this).val() + "]**:visible**").parent().show();
```

But that's no option because it will alway hide all rows when a checkbox is clicked but and then shows the matching one. Works fine when one checkgox filter is activated, but when the second filter is activated he should only filter thru the visible ones, but with this javascript thats no option.

Any one has a solution for this so multi filtering is also possible?

Created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m9jrn5bq/.

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates your issue. We don't know how the checkbox system should work without seeing some html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m9jrn5bq/ here it is.

Comment: not 100% clear what expected behavior is

Comment: When you choose "wit" it will show one result. When you also select "nieuw" it shows two result, but it should only show the first result because the second doenst matches both selected checkboxes. Only the first one does.